# Riesz Representation Theorem and Indicator Function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

I've been dealing with the Riesz Representation Theorem for measures and it is obvious that having a measure $\mu$ I can get a continuous linear functional $\mu^*$ in $C(X)^*$ where $X$ is a compact metric space.

> **What about the converse?**  That is  Given $\mu^*$ in $C(X)^*$ can we fine a measure representing $\mu^*$?

I know that for each element $\mu^*$ in $C(X)^*$ **such that $\mu^*(1)=1$ and $\mu^*(f)\geq 0$, when $f\geq 0$ there exists a unique measure n $X$**.

Intuitively, given $\mu^* \in C(X)^*$ we can define the measure $\mu$ of a (measurable) set $S$ as $\mu^*(1_{S})$ where $1_S$ is the indicator function of $S$.

Is this telling me that the indicator function can be approximated by continuous functions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian You could turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Max What is the answer to this question?